# Test vectors for calculating operation hash

Tags: operation, testing, hash

I am writing code to calculate operation hash from the raw hex and I would like some test vectors to verify my code. Where can I find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test against the data that the official Tezos project uses for regression testing. This file might be of interest:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/tezt/_regressions/protocol.alpha.operation.internal.out

Comment: Still would be nice with everything contained in a file, though. Raw hex  + operation hash.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge Please be sure to mark your questions as 'answered' so they can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: @utdrmac In the comments I asked if the txid + raw hex could be found in the same file. Still waiting to see if that is the case.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge  If you look at  the file in the answer, then your answer is no. They are not found in the same file and adding them would require retooling all of the Tezos build scripts.

Comment: Looking at the file I don't think it solves the problem, as the `branch` of the operation is needed to calculate the `txid`, and that file does not include `branch`